# Why getting error mongod dead but subsys locked and Insufficient free space for journal files on Linux?

Tags: linux, mongodb, journal

I have installed **mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server** on Linux CentOS server.

I followed the steps from [**Link**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/).

I have configured **/etc/mongod.conf** as -

```
logpath=/var/log/mongo/mongod.log
port=27017
dbpath=/var/lib/mongo
```

I have set port 27017 for mongo in **iptables**.
To start mongo I used commands -

```
service mongod start and
mongo
```

It get started well, but after few days I am getting the error -

```
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongo/journal or use --smallfiles
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten]
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 dbexit:
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Jan 29 08:41:54 dbexit: really exiting now
```

When I execute the command -

```
service mongod status
```

It gives Error -

```
mongod dead but subsys locked
```

Please help me to solve the problem of ***mongod dead but subsys locked*** and ***Insufficient free space for journals, terminating***

Comment: It's telling you that you don't have enough free disk space to create the `/var/lib/mongo/journal` file of 3.3GB that it needs so it can't start.

Comment: I had enough space and still got the issue. I have posted what worked for me below.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can add following to the config file provided when running `mongod --config mongod.conf`

For MongoDB **3.x** (latest version)

```
storage:
   mmapv1:
      smallFiles: true
```

For version **2.6+**

```
storage:
   smallFiles: true
```

For version **2.4** and less

```
smallfiles = true
```

Then just execute mongod to accept your config file (here it assumes that location of the config is */etc/mongodb.conf*):

```
mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
```

[Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.smallFiles) for **smallfiles** parameter:

```
Set to true to modify MongoDB to use a smaller default data file size. 
Specifically, smallfiles reduces the initial size for data files and
limits them to 512 megabytes. The smallfiles setting also reduces the
size of each journal files from 1 gigabyte to 128 megabytes.
```

Comment: @Andrei Karpushonak Where is the config file? to setup `samllfiles = true`

Comment: Depending on your OS, on Linux it's /etc/mongodb.conf

Comment: Error parsing INI config file: unrecognized line in 'storage:'
try 'mongod --help' for more information

Comment: I am running 3.0.2 version and the above configuration raised an error, I had to do `smallfiles=true` to make it work.

Comment: Ok not enough free disk space to create the /var/lib/mongo/journal file of => 3.3GB <=  needed

Comment: Strange ..for me 2.6+ setting worked when my mongodb v3.0.15

Answer (score 55):

Start `mongod` instance using following command

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles
```

Comment: Ok not enough free disk space to create the /var/lib/mongo/journal file of => 3.3GB <=  needed

Answer (score 11):

I was following the official guide at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

After using

```
$sudo service mongod start
```

I went to verify if MongoDB had started successfully by reviewing this log:

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

This is the problem that I found:

```
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten]
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.808-0500 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2014-11-11T12:54:05.814-0500 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-11-11T12:54:05.814-0500 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Solution:

At the end of the file /etc/mongod.conf I added this line:

```
smallfiles = true
```

After that, I restarted the mongod service:

```
$sudo service mongod restart
```

Then when I went to review the log, I realized that everything was perfect, and the problem was fixed:

```
2014-11-11T22:32:20.544-0500 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-11-11T22:32:20.552-0500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5200 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=jaimemontoya-VirtualBox
2014-11-11T22:32:20.552-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.5
2014-11-11T22:32:20.552-0500 [initandlisten] git version: e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6
2014-11-11T22:32:20.552-0500 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build8.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-11-11T22:32:20.552-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-11-11T22:32:20.552-0500 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", smallFiles: true }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2014-11-11T22:32:20.564-0500 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
2014-11-11T22:32:20.564-0500 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-11-11T22:32:20.738-0500 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-11-11T22:33:20.748-0500 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:36 virt:245
2014-11-11T22:33:20.748-0500 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):64
2014-11-11T22:33:20.748-0500 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

Comment: Ok not enough free disk space to create the /var/lib/mongo/journal file of => 3.3GB <=  needed

Comment: On my system the file to edit was `/etc/mongodb.conf` instead of `/etc/mongod.conf`

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone having this issue despite having enough space for the journal file to be created.**

My problem: I had more than enough space for the journal file to be created. Mongo gave me a connection failed issue. I used kill command to kill the mongod process which in turn gave me the subsys issue. Here is what worked for me:

Go to `/var/lock/subsys` and delete file `mongod`

now `service mongod stop`and then `service mongod start`

Started mongo shell now and everything seems to be running fine.

Answer (score 0):

first

```
cd /usr/local/src/mongo/bin/<br>
```

then

```
./mongod --dbpath /usr/local/src/mongo/data/db/ --smallfiles
```

Comment: This may solve the problem but it would be nice if you add some explanation to your answer. That will increase the value of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, which helped me. Though there were no technical issue related to mongo. It was just the system's space was insufficient. Clearing the system's cache worked out to me and mongo was back running smoothly.

```
yum clean all
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Background:  I upgraded DB server from t2.micro to the larger instance without **stopping database services**. which in return created this lock file and throwing this error,
 **mongod dead but subsys locked**
After this I was unable to use mongo shell.

If you have enough **disk space**. Then follow these steps,

1.**sudo mongod** 
(if you find below failed reason)

```
Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted)
```

2. Go to **/tmp/** directory
3. Remove **mongodb-27017.sock** file
4. Restart mongod with **sudo service mongod restart**