# MongoDB start with error: mongod dead but subsys locked

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos5

I have installed and I am trying to start a **MongoDB on CentOS Server 5.11, 32-bit, Plesk 12.5.30**.

I have setted some properties on **/etc/mongodb.conf**:

```
#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

# fork and run in background
fork = true

port = 27017

dbpath = /data/db

pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongodb.pid

#add config storage as stackoverflow
smallfiles = true
...
```

The last configuration I have got through this post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584393/why-getting-error-mongod-dead-but-subsys-locked-and-insufficient-free-space-for). But the result was the same...

The **log** shows this:

```
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 db version v1.6.4, pdfile version 4.5
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 git version: nogitversion
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 sys info: Linux x86-12.phx2.fedoraproject.org 2.6.32-71.el6$
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 exception in initAndListen std::exception: dbpath (/var/lib$
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 dbexit:

Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 shutdown: going to flush oplog...
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Dec  3 12:48:39     closeAllFiles() finished

Sat Dec  3 12:48:39 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I tried to start using both commands:

```
service mongod start
```

and

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles
```

And using the command

```
service mongod status
```

The message is

```
mongod dead but subsys locked
```

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-centos-6/) and [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-mean-stack-with-mean-js-on-centos-7). Both of them are not using CentOS 5. Could it be the problem? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Working solution for **mongod dead but subsys locked**, remove mongod file form /var/lock/subsys

**rm -rf /var/lock/subsys/mongod**

and start service mongodb

sudo service mongod start

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who is getting the status message `mongod dead but subsys locked` and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584393/why-getting-error-mongod-dead-but-subsys-locked-and-insufficient-free-space-for) didn't help. I work on SLC6 (which may be closer to CentOS behavior) with MongoDB v1.6.4, and the following worked for me:

```
rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

Unfortunately, I don't remember how I figured that out originally (probably logs), but I found it in my root history when I had the problem a second time.